# How to Debug Django Javascript within VSCode?

Tags: django, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I was wondering if there is a solution to Debug Django Javascript with in VSCode.
VScode Chrome Debuger seems very popular. Is it possible to use that together with Django server enviorment?
untill now i tried following setting in my config:

```
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/static/files"
    },
```

`webRoot` is the same path as my `STATIC_ROOT` constant from `settings.py`

Any Ideas? For me the solution does not to be nessesarly the VSChrome-Debugger, I just dont want to debug JS in Chrome directly all the time ^^.

Thanks!!

Comment: Its just anoying to be switching between editor and browser all the time.  Im sure that im not the only one feeling this way and thought there might be an "easy" solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This setup works for me:

```
{
  "name": "Chrome Debugger - launch",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:8000/v2/",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/project/djangoprojectname/appname/static/main",
  "disableNetworkCache": true
}
```

important is the webRoot. My webRoot path points to where my JS Directory is.
My Django HTML template loads my JS from the folling source:

```
<script type="module" src="{% static 'main/js/index.js' %}"></script>
```

For reference, this is how my complete path looks like: `${workspaceFolder}/project/djangoprojectname/appname/static/main/js/index.js`

---

disableNetworkCache is optional.

Documentation:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug

> disableNetworkCache: If false, the network cache will be NOT disabled. It is disabled by
> default.